# emacs: how to change the foreground color of highlights (e.g., links the point is over)?

Tags: emacs, highlight, emacs-faces

I have a color theme file (similar to gruber-darker.el) and I would like to adjust a specific color. This color can be described as follows: Change to Org Agenda (the org-mode agenda buffer) via `M-x org-agenda a`. Then move the cursor over a Scheduled TODO item (this is a link to the corresponding entry in your agenda file). When the cursor is over such an item, you see the item in highlighted form with a background color and a foreground color. The background color is fine, however, the foreground color is white. I would like to adjust this foreground color to something like `:foreground nil` so that it is not white anymore; instead, the natural color of the item the cursor is on is inherited.
I normally use `M-x describe-face RET` to figure out what the element is that I have to change. However, this does not work here since I only get the colors/element names of the item the cursors is on.

**Update 1:**
I just realized that I get the same behavior for all links in emacs (not only in org-mode). I found out that `(highlight ((t (:background "#453D41"))))` gives me a brown background bar as highlighted region. But once the cursor is over the highlighted region, I get a white foreground color instead of the original color. Even `(highlight ((t (:background "#453D41" :foreground nil))))` does not give me the original color of the item the cursor is on. How can I achieve that?

**Update 2:**
I figured out that `(highlight ((t (:foreground "#000000" :background "#453D41"))))` indeed gives a black foreground color instead of white. But I don't know how to get the "inherited" foreground color of the item the cursor is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have discovered is that it cannot be done. For one thing, the `mouse-face` text property is independent of the `face` property.  For another, face attributes are defined statically; they cannot be inherited dynamically.

Consider filing an Emacs enhancement request for such a capability (it is not limited to `highlight` or to `mouse-face` etc.), using `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  (Yes, that command is for enhancement requests also.)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `describe-char` instead of `describe-face`. That should give you more information about the various faces in use.

Interactively the function uses the character at point but you can also pass it a position, so if you find that placing the cursor on the character in question is a problem (e.g. it changes the highlighting to something else), you can do something like this:

1. Move point to a non-conflicting position nearby (let's say 3 characters prior to the character you're interested in).
2. <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(describe-char (+ 3 (point)))` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Dear phils, thanks, that's interesting. As I noted above in the updates, I *know* that it's the `highlight` face that determines the color, it's just that I don't know how to adjust the `foreground` color of the `highlight`-entry so that it uses the actual color the item has originally. I can change it to "always black" (with the above command) or "always blue", but I can't adjust it so that it takes the color of the underlying text (I thought that `:foreground nil` should work but it does not)

Answer (score 1):

By using `M-x customize-face`, I could not define a background color only for the highlight face without making the foreground color conflict with my theme font-lock.

However, I managed to define an inherited foreground color for the highlight face by defining the highlight face custom before loading my emacs theme.

I use `dracula-theme` and below you will find an example of the very first lines of my init.el file, that solve this precise need.

```lisp
(custom-set-faces
 '(highlight ((t (:background "#222222" :foreground nil))))

;; Setting personal theme
(unless (package-installed-p 'dracula-theme)
  (package-install 'dracula-theme))

(load-theme 'dracula t)
```

I restarted the emacs instance (in my case the daemon) to apply the changes, and it finally worked.